# I try to check a variable for callable in Python 3.x

Tags: django, python-3.x, conditional-statements, callable

I try to check if name is callable. From **john** I expect "I'm a callable" and from **kate** "I'm not a callable". But I get "I'm not a callable" twice

```
def name(first_name, last_name):
  return first_name+' '+last_name

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        if callable(self.name):
            print("I'm a callable")
        else:
            print("I'm not a callable")

john = Person( name('John', 'Green'))
kate = Person("Kate")
```

The result is:

```
I'm not a callable
I'm not a callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an str object in both examples which isn't callable. Compare:

```
>>> a = Person(name('John', 'Watson'))
I'm not a callable
>>> a = Person(name)
I'm a callable
```

name() is callable while its return value isn't.